# How to compare aspect ratios?

Tags: graphics, conditionals, width, includegraphics, calculations

I have a box whose side lengths are recorded as lengths as in

```latex
\newlength{\imageWidth} \setlength{\imageWidth}{300mm}
\newlength{\imageHeight} \setlength{\imageHeight}{200mm}
```

I am trying to create a command which takes a file name of a picture as an argument, and places the picture inside the box in such a way that the aspect ratio is preserved and the box is filled entirely (if the aspect ratio of the image is wider than the aspect ratio of the box, then the left and the right and side should be clipped).

To do so I first need to compare the aspect ratios. What I am trying is

```
\settowidth{\imageFileWidth}{\includegraphics{#1}}
\settoheight{\imageFileHeight}{\includegraphics{#1}}

\ifnum\ratio{\imageFileWidth}{\imageFileHeight}>\ratio{\imageWidth}{\calHeight}
    \includegraphics[height=\imageHeight]{#1}
\else
    \includegraphics[width=\imageWidth]{#1}
\fi
```

using the `calc` package. But it does not work, I keep getting `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)` and `Missing = inserted for \ifnum` errors.

Any advice?

**Update** Solved thanks to the excellent answer by *mbert*. I am now using this code for a minimalistic photo calendar class [photocal](https://github.com/wirhabenzeit/photocal)

Comment: keepaspectratio does nothing if you only specify one of `height` or `width`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\fpeval` to produce 0 if the ratio is smaller, 1 if it is larger. I added some extra descriptive information in the branches of `\ifnum` that you can remove for your actual use case. I also decreased the `\imageWidth` and `\imageHeight` so the images didn't go off the page, at least with the dimensions of the article class.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\imageWidth}
\setlength{\imageWidth}{60mm}
\newlength{\imageHeight}
\setlength{\imageHeight}{40mm}
\newlength{\imageFileWidth}
\newlength{\imageFileHeight}

\newcommand{\custompic}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\imageFileWidth}{\includegraphics{#1}}%
  \settoheight{\imageFileHeight}{\includegraphics{#1}}%
  \ifnum\fpeval{\the\imageFileWidth/\the\imageFileHeight > \the\imageWidth/\the\imageHeight}=1
    Greater:
    \fpeval{ceil(\the\imageFileWidth/\the\imageFileHeight,2)}%
    \textgreater
    \fpeval{ceil(\the\imageWidth/\the\imageHeight,2)}\par
    \includegraphics[height=\imageHeight]{#1}%
  \else
    Less:
    \fpeval{ceil(\the\imageFileWidth/\the\imageFileHeight,2)}%
    \textless
    \fpeval{ceil(\the\imageWidth/\the\imageHeight,2)}\par
    \includegraphics[width=\imageWidth]{#1}%
  \fi
  }

\begin{document}

\custompic{example-image-duck}

\custompic{example-image-4x3}

\end{document}
```

[image: pics]

Just for fun, here's an expl3 implementation. Suggested improvements welcome.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_const:Nn \c_julian_width_dim { 60mm }
\dim_const:Nn \c_julian_height_dim { 40mm }
\fp_new:N \l_julian_fixedratio_fp
\fp_set:Nn \l_julian_fixedratio_fp
  {
    \dim_ratio:nn { \c_julian_width_dim } { \c_julian_height_dim }
  }
\fp_new:N \l_julian_tmpratio_fp
\box_new:N \l_julian_image_box
\cs_new:Nn \julian_custom_pic:n
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_julian_image_box { \includegraphics{#1} }
    \fp_set:Nn \l_julian_tmpratio_fp
      {
        \dim_ratio:nn { \box_wd:N \l_julian_image_box } { \box_ht:N \l_julian_image_box }
      }
    \fp_compare:nNnTF { \l_julian_tmpratio_fp } > { \l_julian_fixedratio_fp }
      {
        Greater:~
        \fp_eval:n { ceil( \l_julian_tmpratio_fp, 2 ) }
        \textgreater
        \fp_eval:n { ceil( \l_julian_fixedratio_fp, 2 ) }\par
        \includegraphics[height=\c_julian_height_dim]{#1}%
      }
      {
        Less:~
        \fp_eval:n { ceil( \l_julian_tmpratio_fp, 2 ) }
        \textless
        \fp_eval:n { ceil( \l_julian_fixedratio_fp, 2 ) }\par
        \includegraphics[width=\c_julian_width_dim]{#1}%
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \custompic } { m } { \julian_custom_pic:n { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\custompic{example-image-duck}

\custompic{example-image-4x3}

\end{document}
```

Again for fun, here's a version that shows the region clipped.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_const:Nn \c_julian_width_dim { 60mm }
\dim_const:Nn \c_julian_height_dim { 40mm }
\fp_new:N \l_julian_fixedratio_fp
\fp_set:Nn \l_julian_fixedratio_fp
  {
    \dim_ratio:nn { \c_julian_width_dim } { \c_julian_height_dim }
  }
\fp_new:N \l_julian_tmpratio_fp
\box_new:N \l_julian_image_box
\cs_new:Nn \julian_custom_pic:n
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_julian_image_box { \includegraphics{#1} }
    \fp_set:Nn \l_julian_tmpratio_fp
      {
        \dim_ratio:nn { \box_wd:N \l_julian_image_box } { \box_ht:N \l_julian_image_box }
      }
    \fp_compare:nNnTF { \l_julian_tmpratio_fp } > { \l_julian_fixedratio_fp }
      {
        \includegraphics[height=\c_julian_height_dim]{#1}%
      }
      {
        \includegraphics[width=\c_julian_width_dim]{#1}%
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \custompic } { m } { \julian_custom_pic:n { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\linethickness{1pt}

\newcommand{\showclip}[1]{%
  \begin{picture}(60,40)
  \color{red}
  \put(0,0){#1}
  \put(0,0){\line(0,1){40}}
  \put(60,0){\line(0,1){40}}
  \put(0,0){\line(1,0){60}}
  \put(0,40){\line(1,0){60}}
  \end{picture}
}

\begin{document}

\showclip{\custompic{example-image-duck}}

\vspace{1cm}

\showclip{\custompic{example-image-4x3}}

\end{document}
```

[image: showclip]

Comment: Where does `\fpeval` come from?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides It’s in the kernel, documented in usrguide

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at interface3! The fp package also has one but I did not see you loading it.

Comment: To be honest I am not too sure, if I am happy with this sort of command to go in the kernel. I am much happier to use the l3fp  module, for this. It pushes people in the wrong direction.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides See updated answer. Suggestions welcome :)

Comment: Code looks more cleaner and readable now. I am not too sure if I understand the OP correctly as one can simply do `\includegraphics[width=60mm,height=40mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}`

Comment: If one needs to do clipping is a different situation. For example you might have an image wider than the page, that you want to fix it to the height to paper height and the width of th page you may need to do clipping either with tikz or clip key

Comment: Try with a full page image (say for a cover page) and you will see the issue. If the box and the image do not have the same aspect ratio, you cannot fill the box with the image, you might have white spaces or overflow outside the box.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I'm a bit confused, I thought the whole idea was to have overflow and eventually clip what's outside the box. I added a version that shows the region to be clipped. But as far as I can tell there should never be whitespace inside the box

Comment: @mbert Thanks again for this great answer. I added a reference to this post on my photo calendar class on https://github.com/wirhabenzeit/photocal